# Disabling Redfish 'host interface' via API (i.e. usb0)

Tags: redfish

I want to disable the USB 'host' NIC present in some Redfish implementations. I want to do this in order to remove the enp10xxxxxxxx device which pops up inside an operating system running on hardware with this feature.

According to the docs this should be possible like this:

```
# Disable the host interface 
curl -sku ${username_password} -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "If-Match:*" https://$BMC_ADDRESS/redfish/v1/Managers/Self/HostInterfaces/Self -d '{"InterfaceEnabled": false}' | jq -r
```

This 'works' and I see:

```
 "Status": {
    "Health": "OK",
    "State": "Disabled"
  }
}
```

... however the BMC and, more importantly, the OS still see the usb0 device.

Can anyone please point out where I might be going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: This is ignorance/curiosity on my part - what server is this on? I haven't seen this before. On Dell servers you can get to the iDRAC over microUSB but that interface doesn't show up on the operating system. Is this USB NIC you see meant to be for the host OS?